# Trying to get my .net core application to run in visual studio code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, project.json

My windows hard drive recently bit the dust recently where I was working on an angular 2 .net core application with vs 2015 using .net core 1.1. I have a computer with ubuntu on it so I though why not just download vs code and clone my project and get to work right..... Well I am having problems and hopefully someone can help.

I install c# I install C# extensions. but this is the error I get

> Build FAILED.
>   /home/deshazer/Documents/code/HannaOilGas2/HannaOilAndGas2/project.json(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
>       0 Warning(s)
>       1 Error(s)
>   Time Elapsed 00:00:00.06

now my project.json file looks like this

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "appsettings.json",
      "ClientApp/dist",
      "node_modules",
      "Views",
      "web.config",
      "wwwroot"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod"
    ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "HannaOilAndGas2"
  }
}
```

I am also seeing problems with my models and in my controllers I am using web api can anyone help me out with this in vs code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HannaOilAndGas2.Data
{
    public partial class MainView
    {
        public int RecId { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public double? SpotFlowRate { get; set; }
        public double? PreviousDayVolume { get; set; }
        public double? LinePressure { get; set; }
        public double? DifferentialPressure { get; set; }
        public double? Temperature { get; set; }
        public double? BatteryVoltage { get; set; }
        public double? Fcp { get; set; }
        public double? Ftp { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string LastCommunicationMethod { get; set; }
        public string MeterId { get; set; }
        public string ImportMethod { get; set; }
        public int HannaDeviceId { get; set; }


    }
}
```

saying type system could not be found and its asking me to put the int to methods eh.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using HannaOilAndGas2.Data;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace HannaOilAndGas2.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/mainview")]
    public class MainViewApi : Controller
    {
        private readonly ScadaContext _context;

        public MainViewApi(ScadaContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("allmainview")]          //front end - done
        public IEnumerable<MainView> GetAllMainView()
        {
            return _context.Main_View.Where(x => !x.MeterId.StartsWith("HOGC"));            
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("allwinccuview")]        //front end - done
        public IEnumerable<MainView> GetAllWinccuView()
        {
            return _context.Main_View.Where(x => x.ImportMethod == "WINCCU" );
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("allmanualview")]        //front end - done
        public IEnumerable<MainView> GetAllManualView()
        {
            return _context.Main_View.Where(x => x.ImportMethod == "SPREADSHEET");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("allservicestarview")]   //front end - done
        public IEnumerable<MainView> GetAllServiceStarView()
        {
            return _context.Main_View.Where(x => x.ImportMethod == "SERVICESTAR-POLL");
        }

        [Route("allcanadaview")]        //front end - done
        public IEnumerable<MainView> GetAllCanadaView()
        {
            return _context.Main_View.Where(x => x.MeterId.StartsWith("HOGC"));
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IEnumerable<MainView> GetMainViewDataById(int id)
        {
            return _context.Main_View.Where(x => x.RecId == id);
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

this is saying predefined type system string is not defined or imported netcoreapp1.1 again that is in my project.json please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using the latest .NET Core SDK on Ubuntu? What do you get when you run `dotnet --version` on the Terminal? The problem might be that your app is using `project.json`, but your .NET Core SDK version is looking for .csproj, which is requires MSBuild conversion.

Comment: @Set I have dot net 1.0.1

Comment: I did generate a .csproj now but I am getting MSBUILD: error MSB1009: project file does not exist. it says this is the runtime framework version <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project.json is changed back to .csproj. i would suggest you to migrate your project using

dotnet migrate command

In CLI as you're running in Linux.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion I tried to do this but now I get MSBuild: error MSB1009: project file does not exist

Comment: check the path , change the path to the location of your project file

Comment: not totally sure how to do this change the path I am probably just going to get a windows machine back up and work in vs 2015. I opened the project just fine on my laptop with vs 2015 and was able to work right away. I was hoping they would of made it easier to go from vs 2015 to vs code considering I was using .net core